# Javascript templating values coming from JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a Javascript template with tables and I want to replace the values with JSON data. But I am having a hard time replacing the template data with JSON. maybe I am confusing you but http://jsfiddle.net/k6pJz/ is where I am. All your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: are you fixed on using mootools or would you be happy using jquery

Comment: Well, one of your regular expressions seems to be broken, and you have a statement beginning with a dot. Why not check the error console?

Comment: Did you notice the syntax errors being reported?

Comment: yeah. not sure how to replace the firstName and the lastName in the template

Comment: I tried loading with jquery and  template.replace( '{{FirstName}}', msg[i].firstName); but doesnt work.

Comment: knockoutJS has a greate templating engine, but I think it requires jQuery.  http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/k6pJz/10/

This code had multiple syntax errors, and malformed JSON. And would still not have worked afte that.  To name a few:

- JSON had a smart quote ” instead of the only valid JSON quote character ".
- JSON was missing the last closing quote
- You had had a receiver less method call after a line with a semi colon which doesn't work at all. `foo.innerHTML; .replace('a', 'b')`
- Your second regex does not start with a `/` character.
- You never reassigned the value of the parsed template back to the `.data` element.

Lastly, you may want to look into some templating libraries like the one [built into jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) or [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js).  Thats only two but there are tons, and they make your life much easier.

Comment: Thanks Perfect but how come we aren't getting the second value?

Comment: Because the approach is flawed.  On the first time through the loop it loads the template, replaces the tags with data then writes it back to the page.  The second time through the loop it does the same thing, but there are no more `{{}}` tags anymore.  So nothing actually gets replaced.

Comment: ooh ok right. what changes I need to make inorder to make it load all the elements.

Comment: do you think making an id for the template and calling it again will work?

Comment: You are a smart guy, I'm sure you can figure out how to setup a loop to build a string.  And if you don't really know what that means then perhaps writing a templating engine may be a bit beyond your current understanding of JavaScript.  I would suggest some training around JavaScript basics instead.